Can I install 10TB HDD in Dell T-7500 workstation with Windows 7 Ultimate?
I am using Dell T-7500 workstation with Windows 7 Ultimate.
It has 4 drive bays & currently I am running 1 x 500GB SSD + 1 x 2TB SSD + 1 x 6 TB HDD6 TB HDD,
I want to replace 6TB HDD with a new 10TB HDD.
The Dell spec sheet says maximum Storage capacity is 10TB.
Does that mean, I will not be able to run that 10TB HDD with other two SSDs I mentioned?
Here is a link to T-7500 Spec sheer:

https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/uk/dell_precision_t7500_specsheet.pdf


Its 10TB per drive, and its entirely possible its the largest size its validated with, and bigger drives than 10tb might work. I've never seen a machine specified with a maximum total size of storage. Its by disk size and with workstations they're often based off what was tested/qualified rather than what could work.
The controller here's a Integrated LSI 1068e - I can't find a datasheet for it, but if you can run a 6tb drive, you can add or replace it with a 10tb drive

I've never seen a machine specified with a maximum total size of storage. That is what the Pdf file specs says as 10 TB Maximum storage.

No, it’s actually 10 TB in total—5 drives à 2 TB. However, those are the specs of machines as shipped by Dell. It’s not about aftermarket modifications. 10 TB drives did not exist yet when this PC was on the market.

hm, that seems plausible. I really wish the documentation was clearer tho

On the other hand, the machine is running with a 6tb disk

@Dan - I have, many times, last time I saw it were for machines more than a decade old.

Could I go to someone OR the seller who has Win-11 on their system & get it formatted by them ? Would Win-7 then still create detection problem ? OR is it like chicken & egg. Which came first ?

I'm more concerned with HW support - if its just formatting, there's ways around it
